# Rails 4.1: Controller action not being called

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following Controller code that renders another controller action in the same controller:

```
  def create
    @school_application = SchoolApplication.new(school_application_params)
    @school_application.program_cost = @school_application.calculate_cost_to_charge(params[:school_application][:program],     params[:school_application][:duration])
    if @school_application.save
      Rails.logger.debug("Hey mufugga")
      render action: 'view'
    else  
      flash.now[:error] = "There was a problem with your application"
      render action: "new"
    end
 end
```

when `render action: 'view'` is called the appropriate view, `view.html.haml` is called but my `Rails.logger.debug` line does not print in my server log and all the other variables are not set in my view (Which uses the variables). Can anybody tell what is going on? Here is the view controller method.

```
  def view
   Rails.logger.debug("Hello")
   @school_application =SchoolApplication.find(params[:id])
   Rails.logger.debug(@school_application)
   @sevic = SchoolApplication.sevic(@school_application.sevic)
   @cost = @school_application.program_cost.to_i + @sevic.to_i 
   Rails.logger.debug(@cost)
   session[:cost] = @cost
  end
```

N.B. Here is the Rails lolg response to the create request and the successfull and unsuccessfull `logger` outputs:

```
Started POST "/application/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-29 13:56:56 -0700
Processing by SchoolApplicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"cl9CZCC2numQ1aCckWkXizXESByZxOFrb/pl8vhA6YQ=", "school_application"=>{"first_name"=>"d", "family_name"=>"dfg", "sevic"=>"1", "unaccompanied_minor_option"=>"1", "I_20"=>"1", "fls_center"=>"4", "start_date"=>"2014-07-30", "duration"=>"1", "housing_type"=>"22", "health_insurance"=>"1", "transfer_student"=>"1", "comments"=>"d", "gender"=>"dfg", "address"=>"d", "city_state_province"=>"d", "postal_code"=>"d", "country"=>"d", "phone_number"=>"d", "email"=>"d", "date_of_birth"=>"2014-08-05", "arrival_airport"=>"3", "read_everything"=>"1", "country_of_birth"=>"d", "country_of_citizenship"=>"d", "work_with_ad"=>"1", "pay_application_fee_or_full"=>"1", "agency"=>"d", "fax_number"=>"d", "program"=>"7"}, "commit"=>"Continue"}
Unpermitted parameters: unaccompanied_minor_option
  PricePlan Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "price_plans".* FROM "price_plans"  WHERE "price_plans"."program_id" = 7  ORDER BY "price_plans"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "school_applications" ("I_20", "address", "agency",     "arrival_airport", "city_state_province", "comments", "country", "country_of_birth", "country_of_citizenship", "created_at", "date_of_birth", "duration", "email", "family_name", "fax_number", "first_name", "fls_center", "gender", "health_insurance", "housing_type",  "pay_application_fee_or_full", "phone_number", "postal_code", "program", "program_cost", "    read_everything", "sevic", "start_date", "transfer_student", "updated_at", "work_with_ad")   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31) RETURNING "id"  [["I_20", "t"], ["address", "d"], ["agency", "d"], ["arrival_airport", "3"], ["city_state_province", "d"], ["comments", "d"], ["country", "d"], ["country_of_birth", "d"], ["country_of_citizenship", "d"], ["created_at", "2014-08-29 20:56:56.726865"], ["date_of_birth", "2014-08-05"], ["duration", 1], ["email", "d"], ["family_name", "dfg"], ["fax_number", "d"], ["first_name", "d"], ["fls_center", "4"], ["gender", "dfg"], ["health_insurance", "t"], ["housing_type", "22"], ["pay_application_fee_or_full", "t"], ["phone_number", "d"], ["postal_code", "d"], ["program", "7"], ["program_cost", "475.00"], ["read_everything", "t"], ["sevic", "t"], ["start_date", "2014-07-30"], ["transfer_student", "t"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-29 20:56:56.726865"], ["work_with_ad", "t"]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Hey mufugga
  Rendered application/view.html.haml within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_top_nav.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 15.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It turns out I misunderstood what exactly `render :action =>` does. After revisiting the rails guides, I realized that it only renders the view corresponding to that action, which was not the behavior I was anticipating, and therefore the controller action corresponding to the view I was rendering was not called.

What I wanted to do was solved by calling `redirect_to` to the url that has the action I was calling, which thus created the desired response from the server.